# Possible to hover over a PNG image?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to hover over a PNG image using CSS/jQuery?

Or, would I be better off creating the element (say, a star) using pure CSS3?

Comment: Either way is fine, just place the path of PNG image in the `src` of an `<img>` tag. Alternative elements is a feasible option as well but there's no `<star>` element that I know of.

Comment: please show some code... so i can think, in which way u want to  way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both:

jQuery:

```
$('.someclass').hover(function(){
   // code goes here $(this).css({'border-color':'#fff'});
});
```

CSS:

```
.someclass { border-color: red; }
.someclass:hover { border-color:#fff; }
```

I personally recommand using pure css as I have seen that it works better on mobile phones specially when animatioan and transitions are used.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cause the cursor to hover anywhere with CSS or jQuery.  I would recommend downloading AutoHotKey and creating a script with that if you want to move your cursor and hover over a picture.  With AutoHotKey, you can move your mouse anywhere on the screen-- even on top of PNG images!

You could try making a star with pure CSS3, but I don't think that will work.  I have never heard of a CSS star moving the mouse to a specified location.  If you want to try it, however, here is the code:

```
<star color="yellow" border="thin solid black" pointCount="5" height="50px" width="50px" />
```

Let me know how it goes!